# How to use string value as url from json file to create Firebase reference?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, firebase

I'm new to Angular and Firebase and i'm doing some experiments. I have a json file located on my server and everything is working perfect with the $http.get request. The problem is that i can't make a Firebase database reference with url specified from the json file string value that i requested with $http.get

My code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['firebase']);    
app.controller("ListController", function($scope, $http) {     $http.get("http://myhomeserver.localtunnel.me/json/localhost.json").then(function(response) {
    $scope.jsonFromServer = response.data.colorsLink[0].firebase;   
    $scope.jsonFromFirebase = function($firebaseArray) {
        var ref = new Firebase($scope.jsonFromServer);
        $scope.test = $firebaseArray(ref);
    }
        });
 });
```

The json file on my server:

```
{
"colorsLink":[
    {
        "firebase":"https://intense-torch-5483.firebaseio.com/test",
        "hexValue":"#f00"
    },
    {
        "colorName":"green",
        "hexValue":"#0f0"
    },
    {
        "colorName":"blue",
        "hexValue":"#00f"
    },
    {
        "colorName":"cyan",
        "hexValue":"#0ff"
    },
    {
        "colorName":"magenta",
        "hexValue":"#f0f"
    },
    {
        "colorName":"yellow",
        "hexValue":"#ff0"
    },
    {
        "colorName":"black",
        "hexValue":"#000"
    }
]
}
```

Can someone please help me with this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: You are referencing `ColorsLink[0].firebase`, but in your JSON it is camel case `colorsLink`

Comment: Sorry it's a mistake. Even if i referencing with colorsLink[0].firebase i can't make a Firebase reference.